# git is always asking for arbitary location

Tags: git

Always when I try to pull commit, git is asking me for `arbitary location` of repository.

I want to put for that dir constant `arbitary location`, so in future I will not have to put manually address of repo.

How can resolve it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a default `remote` repo you want to push your changes to.

```
git remote add <remote_name> <remote_url>
```

The remote URL can be set to a local path too.

Then set this remote as the default during the first push:

```
git push -u <remote_name>
```

In future you can just `git push` and it will be pushed to your remote.